# CakePHP on GoDaddy

Tags: cakephp

i am pretty new to this and i want to set up my cakephp trunk on godaddy. I uploaded the trunk on the httpdocs/ folder. can someone help me out please as it seems that it's not locating the main index.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok...lets say your root directory is /mysite/, inside /mysite/ directory your cakephp code will look like this:

```
/mysite/
       /app
       /lib
       /vendors
       /plugins
       /.htaccess
       /index.php
       /README
```

Now open .htaccess and add below line

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it will help

Comment: HI, Thanks for your help. do you mean like this "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteBase / 
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>"

Comment: i get a 500 internal server error. Do i have to modify the index.php file by any chance?

Comment: No need to change index.php, .htaccess is creating problem in your case...pls check if the code is coming to your index.php by applying echo on top of the file. if it is not coming then .htaccess need some modifications

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. i echoed something and exited the page <echo "testing"; die();> and it echoed it, so it's going in the index.php file. so there must be something in the index.php which is giving me the internal server error

Comment: tried some logs and found where the problem lies. its in the app/webroot/index.php file:  if (!include (CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS . 'Cake' . DS . 'bootstrap.php')) {
  $failed = true;
 }

Comment: this alsow gave an error: $Dispatcher->dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse(array('charset' => Configure::read('App.encoding'))));

Comment: ohhhh...now you have to apply echo in every if n else condition and also print and check global variable values...they might help you...well I had done one cakephp 2x website hosting on godaddy so it is not their fault at all....we are missing something.\

Comment: I confirm that the error is coming from the lib/Cake/bootstrap.php <Configure::bootstrap(isset($boot) ? $boot : true);> have been trying to solve this but no luck so far. any help?

Comment: Please share the values of ROOT, APP_DIR, WEBROOT_DIR, WWW_ROOT, CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, and pls do mention your website root path. I will try to find solution...

Comment: ROOT:G:\PleskVhosts\top-casinos-bonuses.com\httpdocs
APP_DIR: app
WEBROOT_DIR: webroot
WWW_ROOT:G:\PleskVhosts\top-casinos-bonuses.com\httpdocs\app\webroot\
CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH:G:\PleskVhosts\top-casinos-bonuses.com\httpdocs\lib

Comment: Ok...every thing is fine except CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH, CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH should be not define, function_exists('ini_set') should be true and ini_set('include_path', ROOT . DS . 'lib' . PATH_SEPARATOR . ini_get('include_path')); must be executed.

Comment: THanks for the help. the problem however seemed to have moved to App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing');

Comment: When i die(); right before the App::uses('Dispatcher', 'Routing'); , i get a blank page, and when i paste the die(); right after the statement, i get the 500 Internal server error.

Comment: Are you using godaddy shared hosting or dedicated server hosting?

Comment: i'm using godaddy Economy Windows Hosting with Plesk..i guess it's shared hosting

Comment: Have you already tried RewriteBase / in .htaccess file?

Comment: yes: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: hi, i told godaddy to switch on the error logs for me. Basically i'm getting the unable to write error. I checked the folder and subfolder permissions and they all have write permissions. Warning: _cake_core_ cache was unable to write 'cake_dev_en-us' to File cache in G:\PleskVhosts\top-casinos-bonuses.com\httpdocs\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 325

Comment: Fixed. all i had to do is remove the 3 htaccess files, and move the css,img,js folder under the main root

Comment: Great... .htaccess file is the real culprit